# what is the probability that $y\le \sin x$?

Tags: probability

We need to find in a rectangle $[0,{\pi\over 2}]\times [0,1]$ a point $(x,y)$ is chosen at random what is the probability that $y\le \sin x$?

Will it be $${\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \ dx\over \pi/2}$$

Comment: No idea, really? What about "area of set of favorable cases" divided by "total area"?

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking, my calculation is correct?

Comment: Looks like the definition to me.

Comment: This is a problem on a 'geometric probability'. Namely, you have a bounded set of possible outcomes with a uniform distribution on it, and you're asked what's the probability of its certain subset. In your case the density if $f(x,y) = \frac2\pi$ whenever $(x,y)$ is in the rectangle, and $0$ otherwise. Thus, your formula is correct: you just integrate the density over the area which satisfies the inequality.

Comment: @Ilya thanku very much for introducing such a new theme to me'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution of the point $(x,y)$ is uniform on the rectangle.  Therefore, you just divide the area of the region where $y \le \sin(x)$ by the area of the entire region.